# Angular/cli command not found on raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, angular-cli, raspbian

im trying to install angular/cli on my raspberry with raspbian lite as OS
i start installing npm 
updating it to the latest versione and running the command npm install @angular/cli
it seems working but when i run command "ng" it says command not found
where im wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the command you used was actually `npm install @angular/cli`, the issue is that you need the angular cli installed globally, not just local to the folder/project you are in. You are just missing `-g` in the command: `npm install @angular/cli -g`.